# don't send email to to-recipient

Tags: email, email-headers, email-forwarding

#### question:

Is it possible **not** to send an email to the to-recipient seen by the CC/BCC-recipients ?

In other words: Is it possible to send an email via CC or BCC but **not** to the to-recipient (i.e. the recipient in the 'to' header field) ?

#### example:

Andrew wants Bob to receive either one of these emails **without** actually sending it to Alice:

```
from: Andrew
to: Alice
```

or

```
from: Andrew
to: Alice
cc: Bob
```

Is that possible?

---

I poorly understand the subject matter, but from my readings it appears as though the sender (Andrew) had to use different recipients for the `to` and `envelope-to` fields, but I don't know how this can be achieved.

Does the sender (Andrew) *inevitably* have to [set up his own mail server](https://superuser.com/questions/385088/how-to-send-email-to-only-of-one-the-recipient) to achieve this or is there an easier solution?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems like related to generaring fake origin emails used in phishing and other unethical methods

Comment: You misunderstand my question. My question cannot be used for phishing! Phishing relies on faking the sender address. My question does not at all involve faking the sender address (or any other address for that matter).

Comment: Name Operating System you use.

Comment: Windows and Linux. Thunderbird is my MUA. Thanks.

Comment: `To`, `From`, `CC` and even `BCC` are just headers in the email. You can put in whatever you want, at least if you use a library that gives you control over the headers in your email. For stackoverflow, it's best to include the code you've tried with an explanation on where you are stuck. What happens when you run the code, what did you expect to happen instead? You mention Thunderbird. Stackoverflow is for programming questions only, not for general software usage. That said, if you have a Thunderbird add-on, that's certainly on-topic. Again, we need to see code. See also [ask].

Comment: @Robert: thanks for your very kind guidance. I don't have any code or clue. I just wanted to ask this question for some basic orientation and precisely to find out whether the solution involves coding or merely "general software usage". From your comment and https://superuser.com/a/385093/1320186 I infer that there is no other solution for Andrew than to set up his own mail server and tweak it so that it does some non-standard stuff. If that is the case, I would accept this as the 'correct answer' if you are willing to post this answer. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to run your own mail server, but a regular MUA probably doesn't give you the control over the email headers that you want. You can try and telnet into a mail server and enter SMTP commands, and after the `data` command you can enter any headers you want. Of course you may trigger spam filters when your headers and SMTP envelope from don't match, but passing a `To:` header and not including that email in the envelope is probably fine, especially if the recipients are on different domains.

Comment: @Robert: Thank you. Your comments give me a clearer picture of the situation. Again, I think you have answered my question, so if you want to post your comments as an answer, I'll gladly accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Robert: You said: _"You don't need to run your own mail server. […]. You can try and telnet into a mail server and enter SMTP commands."_ Sorry if I am confused, but don't I need to run or have control over a mail server if I telnet into it? I mean, I can't telnet into the mail serves of email providers like hotmail, yahoo or gmail, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`To`, `From`, `CC` and even `BCC` are just headers in the email. You can put in whatever you want, at least if you use a library that gives you control over the headers in your email.

Let's do a very simple example using telnet to send an email.

First, look up which email servers handle mail for a domain (here gmail.com), e.g., with `host`:

```
robert@here:~$ host gmail.com
gmail.com has address 142.250.115.19
gmail.com has address 142.250.115.83
gmail.com has address 142.250.115.17
gmail.com has address 142.250.115.18
gmail.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4000:803::2005
gmail.com mail is handled by 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

I'll use the first given email server, gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. As per [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) you can connect to a mail server and send an email like this:

```
robert@here:~$ telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 142.250.138.27...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP v9si1145647ooe.55 - gsmtp
```

Each line starting with numbers is the SMTP server's reply. A code in the 200s is ok, a 400 is a temporary error, and a 500 a permanent error.

Next you say "hello", or rather, the "extended hello" (ehlo) and the server replies with all the extensions it supports:

```
ehlo me
250-mx.google.com at your service, [1.2.3.4]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

Then you tell the server you want to send an email, using the `mail from:` command, and telling it the **SMTP envelope sender email address**. If the server accepts the email, it again replies with something that starts with a 200s code.

```
mail from: <me@example.org>
250 2.1.0 OK v9si1145647ooe.55 - gsmtp
```

Then you give the **SMTP envelope recipient**, and the server accepts again with a 200s code:

```
rcpt to: <smtp-env@example.org>
250 2.1.5 OK v9si1145647ooe.55 - gsmtp
```

Next is the `data` command which the server acknowledges with a 354 code, telling you to enter the message:

```
data
354  Go ahead v9si1145647ooe.55 - gsmtp
```

The email is made up of headers, then a blank line, and then the body of the email. The example below is very simplistic, but should work. You specify a `From:` header, a `To:`, maybe a `CC:` or `BCC:` (sic!) header, and of course a `Subject:`, `Date:`, and others.

```
From: me
To: you
CC: me again
Subject: test

Hello, this is a test.
```

Here you see 4 headers (`From`, `To`, `CC`, and `Subject`), followed by the empty line that separates headers and email body, and then the body, which is just that one line.

End the email with a single dot on a line by itself:

```
.
250 2.0.0 OK  1619472375 v9si1145647ooe.55 - gsmtp
```

The server now has accepted the message and should either deliver or bounce it. You can now send another email (start over with `mail from:` above) or end the dialog:

```
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection v9si1145647ooe.55 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

As you can see, I've entered `smtp-env@example.org` as the **SMTP envelope** recipient email address. This is the one that matters, this is where the email actually gets sent. Nothing prevents you from adding people to the `CC:` or `BCC:` lines without ever specifying a `rcpt-to:` for them. They will not get the email, but it will look to the recipients that actually do get the email, that these people should also receive it. Nothing prevents you from adding a different email address in the `To:` header than what you used in the `rcpt-to:` command.

Usually, a MUA will add a `To:` or `CC:` header that matches the SMTP envelope address, but that is not required. Not having some of these headers, or having headers not match the SMTP envelope commands, may get you some spam points, however.

You don't need a **user name or password** in many cases. And this is intentionally. For example, you are a gmail user and want to send something to someone on yahoo.com. You will need your gmail user name and password to log in to your gmail account, but you don't need an account with yahoo.com to send email to someone with a yahoo.com account. If you were required to have a login with each email server you could ever want to send to, you'd have to have an insane amount of user names and passwords! This is an advantage of email, it's open, it's free, everybody can run a server and send and receive email.

Du kannst Dir die Welt machen, wie sie Dir gefällt. ;-)

If this whole thing sounds odd, keep in mind that email is an almost 50 years old system, with security, attachments, and non-ascii characters being bolted on over the years, with a constant concern for backwards compatibility. But if you couldn't telnet into other email servers, you'd never be able to send an email to anybody. As the person running the email server, you cannot create accounts for the whole world to be able to receive email from everybody.

When you do this programmatically, it depends on what library you use. Most libraries will set defaults for the headers and let you override headers as needed.

Comment: No, you don't need to enter credentials. I've updated the answer. Try it out and send yourself an email via telnet!

Comment: wow, what a perfect answer. I am truly in awe! Quick question: I don't see you mentioning it, but at some point I certainly have to enter my credentials (email/password), no?

Comment: ok, I see! Thank you, Robert, for helping me understand the world a little better with your awesome answer!